# How to get multiple fields for options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in a select_tag. It works fine. (I'm using select_tag because it is for a search not tied to a model.)

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, :id, :first_name)
```

The current HTML output is:

```
<option value="4">Fred</option>
```

But I want:

```
<option value="4">Fred Flintstone</option>
```

I want to display the full name instead of just the first name. I can't seem to get it to use both fields "first_name" and "last_name" nor can I figure out how to get it to call a method where I concatenate the two fields. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define on your model:

`def name; "#{first_name} #{last_name}";end`

and use:

`options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, :id, :name)`

Answer (score 20):

add method full_name in your model :

```
def full_name
   "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

and use this :

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@customers, :id, :full_name)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, Rails Guy. Bernardo beat you to the punch by 10 minutes so I marked his answer as the "solved" one. I appreciate your help in any case!

Comment: I wouldn't answer, if I reloaded the page, and could see his answer. BTW thanks for upvoting.

Comment: @RailsGuy : thank you, solved the same problem I had. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done in this way, you don't need to write a method in your model.

```
options_from_collections_for_select(
  @customers, :id, ->(ob) { "#{ob.first_name} #{ob.last_name}" }
)
```